# adb shell command not working inside a bash script

Tags: bash, adb, ip-address

I am trying to write a bash script which when run can find the ip address of the device connected through usb. The bash script which is doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ip=$(adb shell 'sudo ip -f inet addr show')
```

Then I am going to use the ip later in the script. But the shell command is giving me an error:

```
error: closed
```

To call the script I just navigated to the directory with terminal where its situated and entered

```
./name_of_script
```

Every shell command is giving me this error. I even tried removing the single quotes. When I tried running the same command outside the script inside a terminal, it worked flawlessly. How to run shell commands in a bash script?
What's wrong?

Comment: does adb need to be in an interactive terminal?  This is some kind of env problem, but someone who knows more will doubtless be along.  It would be helpful to see a minimal script and how you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

On Android there is no sudo, only on rooted devices the `su` binary is present. Therefore you have to change the command to:

```
adb shell su -c 'ip -f inet addr show'
```

But in my tests the used command `ip -f inet addr show` did not need root permissions, the output was the same.

So you can simplify the command to:

```
adb shell ip -f inet addr show
```

Comment: Tried doing this, didn't work

Comment: @Pro what happens if you manually start `adb shell` and the execute the `ip -f inet addr show` command? May your Android device doesn't include the `ip` command or it doesn't work.