# Bash script doesn't function as intented on usb connection

Tags: bash, scripting, adb

I have written a bash script which starts a tcpip port and connects my device to my laptop for wireless debugging. This is the script at `/bin/device_added.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb shell ip -f inet addr show 2> /tmp/scripts.log
ip=$(adb shell ip -f inet addr show | egrep -o '192.*/' | sed 's/.$//')
adb tcpip 5555 
adb connect $ip:5555 
echo "USB device added at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log
```

After configuring permissions with chmod, this works flawlessly on its own. But I want this script to be triggered whenever I plug in usb. I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544204/shell-script-not-running-when-i-connect-a-usb/544205#544205) answer to try to make this work. I created a `80-test.rules` file at `/etc/udev/rules.d` and added this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device",  RUN+="/bin/device_added.sh"
```

and reloaded the rules file using: `sudo udevadm control --reload`
Whenever I plug in usb, the script gets run(the date gets logged in scripts.log) but my device doesn't get connected. What am I doing wrong? Why does the script work properly when I run it manually but not when it is triggered through udev?

Edit: On basis of @markp-fuso's and @Charles Duffy's comment, I tried logging the error to /tmp/scripts.log file. Turns out I am getting this error:

```
line 3: adb: command not found
```

Now the strange part is, I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75402608/adb-shell-command-not-working-inside-a-bash-script) error earlier but I solved it by placing the shell command before the tcpip command(atleast that worked when I ran the script directly). How am I supposed to deal with this error now?

**Update**:
As @markp-fuso pointed out, the problem was that environment variables weren't accessible to that script. Hence I created a the adb's location as a variable in the script and then made that used that variable as throught. My script now:

```
#!/bin/bash

adb=/home/pranil/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
$adb shell ip -f inet addr show 2> /tmp/scripts.log
ip=$($adb shell ip -f inet addr show | egrep -o '192.*/' | sed 's/.$//')
$adb tcpip 5555  
$adb connect $ip:5555  
echo "USB device added at $(date)" >>/tmp/scripts.log
```

This solved the error I was getting in logs but still the adb doesn't get connected at the required port. I have no idea where I am going wrong now. One more thing, after my script runs, the offline emulator is no longer shown as an output of abd devices command.

Comment: I would start by having the script run `adp shell ip -f inet addr show` by itself and append  all output to your `*.log` file; then review the `*.log` file to see if the `adb shell ...` output matches what the script is expecting

Comment: A good place to start is to redirect stderr to a log file and read that log. `exec 2>>/tmp/adb_connect.log` or such earlier in your script. (Mind, using a hardcoded name in `/tmp` has security risks -- an attacker can use symlink attacks to cause arbitrary files to be overwritten -- so it's not something you should keep in-place on an ongoing basis).

Comment: @markp-fuso so you are saying that instead of storing the output of adb shell in a variable i should store it in a file, read that file to get the ip?

Comment: no, as a debugging effort I'm saying do both; by writing to a file you can review said file *after* the script has run to verify what you think is going into the variable; Charles Duffy's recommendation (redirect all stderr to a file) would also be a good idea in case one of the commands (including the standalone `adb shell ...`) is generating an error

Comment: as currently written, and based on the lack of post-execution details, you don't know, for a fact, what's actually stored in `ip` nor do you know if any of the commands (in the script) are generating errors; net result ... add more code to the script to allow for the capture of raw data and (possible) error messages

Comment: @markp-fuso I tried doing that, turns out the adb command is giving me an error `adb: command not found`

Comment: right, so when the script is run from the command line your `PATH` includes the location where `adb` is located; when the script is called by the system your `PATH` does not include the location where `adb` is located; in your script you'll need to first insure your `PATH` (and possibly other OS/system variables) is properly defined before making the `adb` calls; this is comparable to a common scenario with `cron` jobs ... script runs ok from command line but fails when run under `cron`

Comment: @markp-fuso I tried defining the adb's path in the script as a variable and then using that variable. The error got resolved and the script ran but it didn't work

Comment: please update the question to include the latest version of the script and any new error messages you're receiving; also, please expand on what *`it didn't work`* means ... error? no output? wrong output? script hangs? something else?

Comment: @markp-fuso I meant that no errors get logged in scripts.log file but still the adb doesn't get connected. I have updated the question with the latest updates.

Comment: If you add `set -x` to your script, the stderr log created with `exec 2>>file` will also include the commands that are run.

Comment: Anyhow -- in general, `adb=...anything...` and then using `$adb` is not great practice. Better to `export ANDROID_HOME=/home/pranil/Android/Sdk; PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH` so _all_ the platform tools can be found (just using `adb`, not `$adb`), and so if adb wants to find another tool to run it can do that.

Comment: so @CharlesDuffy  i should export ANDROID_HOME and define PATH as you have inside my bash script?

Comment: I'd suggest that, yes. If it still doesn't solve the problem, make the script use `strace` to write a log of what adb is up to during operation, and analyze that log.